# State not updating back after search filter backspace

Tags: reactjs, axios

Good Day, I am making a reactjs search filter using the filter method, my problem is everytime I pressed the backspace it doesn't get back to the original state or the state that I've set in the componentdidMount after ajax call, why is my state not updating back to the state that I've assigned in the componentDidMount?

This is my code.

```
class FilterInputs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  searchHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let itemss = this.state.items;
    let searcjQery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let x = itemss.filter(el => {
      let searchValue = el.rocket.rocket_name.toLowerCase();
      return searchValue.indexOf(searcjQery) !== -1;
    })

    this.setState({
      items: x
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/api`).then(res => {
      const missions = res.data;
      missions.map(item => {
        const xx = item.rocket.rocket_name;
      });
      this.setState({
        items: missions
      });
    });
  }
```

May I know, on what I did wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code for componentDidUpdate ?

Comment: hi @simbathesailor, sorry I mistype its not componentDidUpdate but rather componentDidMount.

Comment: What happends is that you change your state when `searchHandler` runs causing you to lose your state. Its better to add a `searchQuery` to state this way we render our items based on `searchQuery` leaving our `state.items` untouched.

Comment: Don't modify your source of truth, your items array in your state. make a copy of that and use it for filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets set a filter in our `state` named `rocketNameQuery` and render based on that query.

I've changed the code to make it more readable.

```
class FilterInputs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      missions: [],
      // set our filter condition
      rocketNameQuery: '',
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8001/api')
      // extract data to a variable named missions and set our state
      .then(({ data: missions }) => {
        this.setState({ missions });
      });
  }

  searchHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const rocketNameQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    // update rocketNameQuery leaving state.missions untouched
    this.setState({ rocketNameQuery });
  }

  checkFilterQuery(mission, rocketNameQuery) {
    return mission.rocket.rocket_name.toLowerCase() === rocketNameQuery;
  }

  render() {
    const { missions, rocketNameQuery} = this.state;
    return !rocketNameQuery 
      ? missions.map(mission => <div key={/* Add a unique key */}>{/* render logic */}</div>)
      : (
        <div>
          // check if our item rocket name match our rocketNameQuery
          {missions.map(mission => this.checkFilterQuery(mission, rocketNameQuery)
            // match ? render logic
            ? <div key={/* Add a unique key */}>{/* Your render logic here */}</div>
            // no match ? return null which will render nothing
            : null
          ))}
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Asaf Aviv, I've tried your code it works, however is there a way to render the data first and then I can make a filter on it?

Comment: @JohnWick Basically start with all missions => filter when the user filter => when filter is empty show all ?